# Sending String over HTTP

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass over the user email to an ESP module via the localIP address. I am able to do it via a web browser using the address -

http://192.168.1.2/get?email=xyz@xyz.com

For iOS I am trying the following code -

```
if let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {
                         let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.2/get?email=\(email)")!
                         var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                        request.httpMethod = "POST"
                        let emailTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                            guard let data = data,
                            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                            error == nil else
                            {
                                print("error", error ?? "Unknown Error")
                            return
                            }
                            let responseString = String(data : data, encoding : .utf8)
                            print("response String = \(responseString)")
                        }
                        emailTask.resume()
                        
                        
                    
                    }
```

I don't get any errors but the value is not getting passed to the ESP. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Let's clarify: You are doing a POST, but there is no parameter in the request HTTPBody? The path in the url is `get`? I would have then expect a `GET` method, not a `POST` one. Is there a doc?

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that , `"http://192.168.1.2/get?email=\(email)"` is of `http`,

not `https`

Apple discourages the insecure `http`,

You should set like this in `info.plist`,

[image: 44444444]

the item is

> NSAppTransportSecurity